# In the NFL, is it legal to fake an extra point kick and run a two point conversion?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, special-teams

In the NFL, is it legal to fake an extra point kick and instead run a two point conversion?
E.g. they snap to the holder who runs it into the end zone instead of spotting it for the kick.

I would've expected to have seen someone at least attempt it if it was legal, given the occasional fake punts and fake field goals, but I haven't even heard of one.

Comment: The difference between a two-point conversion and a point after isn't nearly as large as the difference between a touchdown and a field goal; typically, if you just need one more point, both you and your opponent know it, so you might as well run a normal play. A fake could work as a surprise momentum changer, but so could an onside kick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is legal.  There was actually a fake 2 point conversion earlier this season in November during the Vikings/Bears game.  You can see the highlights about 50 seconds into this video - http://www.nfl.com/videos/nfl-game-highlights/0ap2000000101022/GameDay-Vikings-vs-Bears-highlights

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's completely legal but, of course, risky. If you're in a situation where you need 2-points you should just line up for two and go for it. Otherwise take your shot at the chip-shot extra point. It's difficult to score in the NFL. Every point counts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, in faking the point after, the play will be longer than a standard 2-point conversion try depending on how they fake it.

Comment: Doesn't matter; PATs are untimed plays.