# With the NFL moving the extra point back, is it still possible to fake the kick and go for two?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, scoring

[Under older NFL rules, it was legal, even if unusual, to line up for an extra point kick but make a try for the endzone to score two points.](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/in-the-nfl-is-it-legal-to-fake-an-extra-point-kick-and-run-a-two-point-conversi)

The linked question and answer are from before a considerable rule change in the NFL. Before, either play would happen from the 2. Now, kicks are from the 15 and two-point tries are from the 2.

Is it still possible to run a fake kick to try for the two-point conversion? The discussion [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/5483/21848) does not clarify.

Comment: Also: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12493/is-there-a-penalty-for-kicking-a-pat-from-the-2-yard-line-in-the-nfl

Comment: The rules don't specify.   I have a firm opinion about what would likely happen, but the 2022 rulebook appears to be silent on it.

Comment: @BowlOfRed If the rules do not specify, I would think it’s business as usual: if you punch it in, you get the points that go along with doing so. What is your take?

Comment: This was answered in the Cowboys - Patriots game, check [here](https://youtu.be/3yFJb769c60?t=254).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A discussion of the opposite play (a kick attempted from the run/pass starting position) on [footballzebras.com](https://www.footballzebras.com/2021/08/faked-extra-point-is-good-but-its-worth-0-points/) notes that the rulebook does not specify this, but declares that this would be legal and still valid for 2 points.

> If a team attempts a kick that does not snap from the 15 (or equivalent yard line after a penalty), it is a touchback, and the conversion attempt fails.
>
> On the other hand, if the line of scrimmage is set for a kick, the offense may still run or pass for two points, particularly if there is a botched snap.

This agrees with my personal opinion of what should happen on the field.

---

Per [ESPN](https://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/38541829/cowboys-fake-pat-throw-defensive-lineman-2-point-conversion), on October 1, 2023, Dallas became the first team to score 2 points on a *fake* field goal try since the attempts were relocated.   (They do point out that the Browns scored 2 on a *blocked* attempt in 2019).

This happened during the 2023 week 4 matchup between the [Patriots and Cowboys](https://www.espn.com/nfl/playbyplay/_/gameId/401547453).  After a Cowboys touchdown early in the 2nd quarter, Dallas lined up for a try in the field goal formation from the 15.  Instead of a kick, the team threw a forward pass and was able to move the ball into the end zone.   The successful try was awarded two points.
[NFL video](https://youtu.be/3yFJb769c60?t=254) on youtube.

Comment: +1 It seems like we’re in agreement that it’s business as usual: punching it in again after a touchdown warrants two points. It does seem like a strange strategy to go for two from so far out, but teams fake punts on 4th and long, so maybe the element of surprise is appealing to some coaches.

Comment: The much more likely situation is that mentioned in the answer: a botched snap and the holder running it in (or similar)

Comment: Does the “touchback” in the quote mean that it would automatically be the opponent’s ball without a kickoff?

Comment: No.  Just the try would fail.  After the try is over, a free kick would be used to put the ball in play.

Comment: It happened! Answer accepted!